# Ruby on Rails AJAX call affects only the first element in collection

Tags: jquery, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3, partial-views

I'm iterating over a collection of elements and trying to get AJAX to work properly on a specific element within the collection.  I'm nesting a few partials in order to iterate over these items and use a `js.erb` call like this:

```
$('#favorite_form').html("<%=j render partial: 'shared/unfavorite', locals: { mission: @mission } %>");
```

This only seems to change the **1st** item in the collection even though I could be clicking the 5th item down the list, for example.

Question: How can I specify (via .js and AJAX) which element to update?  Is this jQuery call not specific enough to the individual element?  The code works in regular HTTP requests, so I'm wondering if there is a way to specify the individual element, but I thought that's what partials did :/

```
Example View ( _favorites.html.erb )

<div id="favorite_form">
  <% if you_favorited_this?(current_user, mission) %>
    <%= render partial: 'shared/unfavorite', locals: { mission: mission } %>
  <% else %>
    <%= render partial: 'shared/favorite', locals: { mission: mission } %>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

Comment: Are there multiple divs with ID "favorite_form"? IDs have to be unique, use classes if there are many.

Comment: specifically `$('#favorite_form')` will only ever match the first occurrence of that ID in the page. `$('.favorite_form')` will get them all if you switch your div over to a class

Comment: @xkickflip thanks.  changed it to a class, and you're right, they do all change!  unfortunately, this is not the desired result.  do you recommend uniquely identifying each element with a unique class name?  i know there has to be a better way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue seems to be selector specificity. One helpful thing is to use [div_for](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/RecordTagHelper.html#method-i-div_for) and [dom_id](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/RecordIdentifier.html#method-i-dom_id). So for instance, since it looks like you're rending "missions":

```
# mission partial
<%= div_for mission do %>
  ...the rest of the partial...
<%= end %>
```

In your js then use something like:

```
$('#<%= dom_id @mission %>').html("<%=j render partial: 'shared/unfavorite', locals: { mission: @mission } %>");
```

You may need to tweak your markup slightly but this is a very good way to get the selector you need for a given record when many are on the same page.

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to only update the item you click on, you can try something like this:

```
$(".favorite_form").click(function() {
    $(this).html("<%=j render partial: 'shared/unfavorite', locals: { mission: @mission } %>");
});
```

The `this` in the callback function will refer only to the element that was actually clicked on.